# Back transformation with power function

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, back-transformation

I have the following distribution, where each observation represents a metric.

$Metric = \frac{NExplored Nodes \times NGenerated Nodes}{NRepeated Nodes}$

This metric is highly correlated (0.99637) to running time of an algorithm, as we can see here:
[image]

Tough, the distribution of my observations is unknown to me.
[image]

Here are a bunch of summary statistic of the distribution:

```
Heuristic  x.Mean       x.SD      x.Min      x.Max (METRIC)

EUCLIDE2D  158000.05  154935.99     702.60  885243.35

Heuristic  x.Mean       x.SD      x.Min      x.Max (Runtime)

EUCLIDE2D 2.706144e+01 2.819881e+01 1.624404e-02 1.655057e+02
```

I'm looking forward to estimate the population mean of the metric. The runtime is machine dependent while the metric gives reproducible results in every single machine.

In an effort to make my data normal I used the $X^{8/25}$ transform.
[image]
Which it did, my data seems to fit a normal distribution, as we can see in the following qq-plot.

[image]
After calculating the confidence intervals I got values: [39.70146 ; 42.57713]

And after back transformation: [99144.88, 123360.5]

Now, this metric is a little abstract to be interpreted as is, so I used the linear regression between runtime and metric and extrapolated that the mean time should be between: [5.135649 ; 6.58325] (it should be much higher, occasions where runtime is lesser than 10 are very rare).

My question is, is there any bias on my back transformation? Should I have a correction term as I have seen on log back transforms?!

**EDIT:** After some investigation I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105867/data-transformation-and-confidence-intervals-for-mean-difference) related post. The variance of $x$ is different from the variance of $f(x)$, thus inference can't be made on transformed variables. The most I can do is calculate an approximation using the delta method. I'm trying to understand the process, if anyone can elucidate me, please do. Thanks

**EDIT 2:** Solved it trough bootstrapping for the standard error. Much faster and easier. Thanks everyone. I believe my mean time CI now.

Comment: 8/25 strikes me as unlikely to be remotely interpretable. You might do better with cube root, though (8/24), as it's a reasonably common transformation (indeed, it's the Wilson-Hilferty for a gamma)

Comment: However, it's not clear why you would need normality. What are you trying to achieve? Confidence interval for what quantity? "Proper" in what sense? In any case you'll need to clarify what you mean by "seems to be off". Note that your transformed variable won't be exactly normal.

Comment: What I mean by "seems off" is that the back transformed interval doesn t seem to capture the majority of my observations. I would expect a much bigger interval. Why I need normality?! How can I calculate a confidence interval on a none normal distribution? :/

Comment: It doesn't? It looks like it contains *almost all* of them to me. What proportion of the observations should it contain? What proportion does it contain? With what standard error? And then, keep in mind that your transformed variable *isn't actually normal*. Confidence interval for what, exactly, and for what purpose? If it's not normal, why draw a normal QQ plot at all? What is this metric? It seems like you should be asking about your underlying problem, rather than coming up with some apparently *ad hoc* solution and then asking about that.

Answer (score 1):

A confidence interval for the *mean*, $\mu$ should *not* contain most of the data for moderate to large $n$. As the sample size grows, that CI grows narrower and narrower and contains a smaller and smaller proportion of the data.

If you wat an interval for individuual data values, rather than the mean, you should construct a prediction interval on your transfiormed scale and back-transform that.